# Could the Web-port of a game made with libgdx work as a Facebook app?

Tags: facebook, libgdx

I've just started out with libgdx, a week ago.

I know now that there are 4 project folders, and so far I was only interested in Desktop and Android versions.

But then I realised that the Web-port of the game which is also simultaneously built along, is in JavaScript. And Facebook apps use JS and HTML and CSS right?

So say i'm making this Android game, and put out its Web-counterpart thanks to libgdx+GWT's magic. Will that work as a Facebook App?

Comment: Hei ronnieaka. So ... have you managed to post your libGDX game onto Facebook? I'm currently trying to find out the same thing, and apparently there isn't a precise answer out there.

Comment: Nah man I didn't put the games on Facebook. I just developed one, for Android. And now I will make more, using Unity - you can make iOS and Android apps with executables for free using it. And Unity makes it better - although if you prefer hand coding, that's another matter.

Comment: Yeah, but the Unity license costs a bunch of $ :) Well, ok then. Thanks.

Comment: Just check this: http://unity3d.com/unity/licenses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work as Facebook does support HTML5 and JavaScript for its apps. [For example, Sky Scraper City is build using HTML5.](https://developers.facebook.com/html5/blog/post/2012/04/17/making-a-speedy-html5-game/) I have no prior experience with GWT but judging from the fact that GWT applications running in production mode are pure JavaScript and HTML (compiled from Java source), these applications may be made into Facebook apps.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps I'll try myself and post back. Although first things first, I'll need to get a hosting space. I assumed Facebook would provide it. They do, thanks to Heroku, but only of 5MB